# Docker for local NodeJS development

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, npm, development-environment

What is the right way to develop app locally in the container, when it is possible to have `node_modules` on my laptop `file system`.

Currently I have following `settings` in the `Dockerfile`

```
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app/
```

And the following `docker-compose`

```
 volumes:
    - "/app/node_modules"
```

In that case I'm able to run `npm` commands in the container, and changes in the `package.json` are reflected in my local source tree. Which is good. But one thing is missing: I don't have locally `node_modules` folder and it means my `IDE` can't see these files.

Is it possible to fix somehow?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldnt develop it locally as normal and then dockerize it?

Comment: With that configuration, changes to to package.json inside the container will not be reflected to the host. The volume is a container volume that will not survive a `docker rm -v`. Perhaps you intended to use a host volume?

Comment: @BMitch Fortunately it works, and I can easily see changes, what I've made in the container, on my host

Comment: That would requre some configuration you have not included in the question above.

Comment: @BMitch I'm really not sure what do you mean. I think I've mentioned everything already

Comment: Without a host path, the volume has no connection back to your host filesystem, it only lives inside the container and private docker folders. So with that volume mount, if you're seeing files modified on your host as a result of the container, there's a configuration to do that which you have not provided here. See [the compose file ref](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volume-driver) on volumes for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all your local environment to the container:

```
COPY ./package.json /app/package.json
WORKDIR /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./src/ /app/src/
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

This approach will literally copy your local environment to the image. Everytime you would make a change to your sources - you would have to rebuild the image and restart the container.

I recommend that you mount your project folder as a volume to the container - with all dependencies, and every change in the sources/dependencies would require just restarting the container (or you can use a supervisor inside the container):

```
VOLUME /app/
WORKDIR /app/
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

When running the container - remember to connect your project directory to the container:

And the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '2'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    image: app
    volumes: [".:/app/"]
```

(I assumed that the `Dockerfile` for your Node.js app is in the same directory as sources, `node_modules` and `docker-compose.yml` )

---

EDIT: The solution posted above is good for local development. If you want to dockerize and deploy your application there are two approaches:

**Copy your local `node_modules` and all sources to the container:**

```
COPY ./node_modules /app/
COPY ./src /app/
COPY ./package.json /app/
WORKDIR /app/
CMD ["npm","run","start"]
```

**Or to use the template from the top of my answer**(it will install all the node_modules during the build - when `package.json` changes) this build is way slower.

Comment: it does not work, `node_modules` folder hidden because of mounting local folder over it. If you can make a github repo with sample express or anything else app it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please mention how you gonna run it? cause there is no `npm install` in the Dockerfile, it means you have install somehow (how?) after your container is up?

Comment: @user1016265 I added a better Readme to the repo. Report if you have any problem. Make sure you understand [volumes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlK1JYsM6Aw)

Comment: @jan-sch Well I think you misunderstood my original message, I don't to install modules locally, I want to install it in the container. Furthermore, in your solution it's unclear how you will deploy your image, If there is no modules installed there?

Comment: @user1016265 Sorry I might have been confused from you talking about your laptop and serving files from IDE. The solution I posted is good for local development.

Comment: @user1016265 I updated the answer - hope that it will be useful

Comment: The thing is that in second your option you won't see folder node_modules on your host after your run your container. The first solution is silly because of you need to install modules locally which is not acceptable. If you try my original solution you'll see that it works like it has to be, only one issue there, node_modules is not available locally, and this brings some issues with IDE

Comment: Why can't you use your local node_modules inside the container?